# Coefficient of $x$ in the expansion of $P(x) = (x+1)(x+3) \cdots (x+2^k-1)$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that the coefficient of $x$ in the expansion of $P(x) = (x+1)(x+3) \cdots (x+2^k-1)$ is $$(1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2^k-1))\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k-1}} \dfrac{1}{2i-1}.$$

For any $x$ in any one of the factors we take, we can pick any other possible combinations of the constant terms in the other sets. How do we use that to derive the formula?

Comment: Just use small k at first and see if you can convince yourself...

Comment: Also I think the denominator should be $2^i-1$

Comment: What's the next term after $(x+3)$ - is it $(x+5)$ or $(x+7)$?

Comment: @dxiv It is $(x+5)$.

Comment: Then your question should not be $(x+2^k-1)$.  It should be $(x+2k-1)$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven The general term is $2i-1$ as the OP just confirmed. I agree that the wording of the question is less than clear. The hidden clue that it can't be $2^i -1$ (as you hinted) is that the sum contains $2^{k-1}$ terms in all.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Once I saw the answer it was clear... nice job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

- the coefficient of $x$ is $P'(0)$
- for any polynomial $P(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x-x_j)$ the derivative can be written as $$P'(x) = P(x) \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x-x_j}$$
- for the given polynomial $n=2^{k-1}$ and $-x_j = 2j-1$ so in the end $$P'(0)=P(0)\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{2 j - 1}$$

Comment: Neat, short and clear. +1

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @dxiv's excellent method:

**Method 1**: when expanding the product, a term of the form $ax$ is obtained by taking all constant coefficients of each factor, except one. Hence the $x$ coefficient of a polynomial $P(x)=(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\dots(x+a_n)$ is

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\prod_{k=1}^na_k}{a_j}=P(0)\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{a_j}
$$

(assuming no $a_j$'s is $0$).

**Method 2**: you can use induction and the special case of the Cauchy product formula $c_1(PQ)=c_0(P)c_1(Q)+c_1(P)c_0(Q)$ (where $c_j(P)$ denotes the coefficient of $x^j$ of a polynomial $P$).